# how to tell VIM to format brackets of functions, conditionals, and loops on new line?

Tags: vim

Is there a way I can tell vim to format brackets on a new line?

For example:

```java
public class Foo {
    private Foo(int a) {
        if (a > 30) {
            // do stuff
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Should become:

```java
public class Foo
{
    private Foo(int a)
    {
        if (a > 30)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Why this? Because by pressing `zc` VIM fold code blocks nicely
if they are format as the second example. In this case, VIM
will fold only the content inside the brackets. If code is formated
as in the first example, VIM will fold not only the content inside
the brackets, but also fold `if (...)`, `for (....)`, `function f()`,
`class Foo()`, and so on. So I'd like to know if there is a way to
tell VIM to format file like in the second example.

Another alternative would be to tell VIM to not fold the content before
the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that quite easily: to substitute the existing '{' characters at
the end of lines (`$`) with a carriage return (`\r`) and a new '{', and then
format things nicely you can do the following two commands (although see the
edit at the end of the answer for an edge case):

```
:%s/{$/\r{

:%norm ==
```

The first command will get to this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    private Foo(int a) 
{
        if (a > 30) 
{
            // do stuff
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
{
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The second command will get to this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    private Foo(int a) 
    {
        if (a > 30) 
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) 
        {
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

(The `%` sign in the above commands means apply to all lines of the file. You
could instead give a range like `:5,10s/{$/\r{`, or you could use relative line
numbers like `-2,+3s/{$/\r{`, or select the lines in visual mode and hit `:`
and the substitution command will apply to those lines).

(You could also apply the formatting with `=ap` to format `a` `p`aragraph, see
`:help =` for details)

##### Edit

From the comment by @blackyellow: It is a good solution but one problem is that
it also replaces the lines with '}' which are already formatted correctly. A
better pattern is `:%s/[^(  |\t)]}$/\r{`, which will not replace lines with '}'
at the end if the '}' is preceded by two spaces or a tab, which indicates it is
probably correctly indented.

Comment: it is a good solution but one problem is that it also replaces the lines with `}` which are already formatted correctly.

Comment: A better pattern is `:%s/[^(  |\t)]}$/\r{`, which will not replace lines with `}` at the end if the `}` is preeced by two spaces or a tab, which indicates it is probably correctly indented.

Comment: cheers @blackyellow, I pasted your comments into the answer.